# What is the correct syntax for Date format in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL Developer Version 18.2.0.183, Build 183.1748 (READ ONLY ACCESS TO DB FOR QUERIES)

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
DBSTAGE.DATE_FORMAT(DBSTAGE.OAWOM.CHECKINDATE) "Checked In Date MM/DD/YYYY"
FROM 
DBSTAGE.OAWOM
WHERE
DBSTAGE.OAWOM.WOSTATUS = 'CP'
```

In the CHECKINDATE field portion of My query it returns data in the date format  of 15-FEB-19 which is a DD-MM-YY format. I need it to instead be in the format of MM/DD/YYYY. I don't know how to accomplish that, Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, you use `to_char()` to convert the date to a string in the format you want:

```
select to_char(datecol, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

For specifying literals in a query, I strongly recommend the `date` keyword with YYYY-MM-DD standard format:

```
select date '1776-07-04'
```

You seem to want:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(o.CHECKINDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as checkindate_mmddyyyy
FROM DBSTAGE.OAWOM o
WHERE o.WOSTATUS = 'CP';
```

EDIT:

You may need the function `DBSTAGE.DATE_FORMAT()` to convert your column to a valid date format:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DBSTAGE.DATE_FORMAT(o.CHECKINDATE), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as checkindate_mmddyyyy
FROM DBSTAGE.OAWOM o
WHERE o.WOSTATUS = 'CP';
```

Comment: I have read about the to_char but I can't seem to get the syntax correct for it, can you please advise specifically how to enter that using my query?

Comment: Yep that's the SCHEMA, TABLE and FIELD. That's exactly what I tried but i get this error when I do:

ORA-01481: invalid number format model
01481. 00000 -  "invalid number format model"
*Cause:    The user is attempting to either convert a number to a string
           via TO_CHAR or a string to a number via TO_NUMBER and has
           supplied an invalid number format model parameter.
*Action:   Consult your manual.


Please advise.

Comment: The date format is fine.  The column would appear not to be a date, contrary to what your question says.

Comment: Well poop. in that same query if i dont use the... DBSTAGE.DATE_FORMAT( ...and remove the other... ) .... from my original query It outputs the date in the format of 1190214 which is 1+YYMMDD. Does that help come up with a solution?